# Getting error when starting a brand new generator-built app

Tags: node.js, express

Greenie here. Trying to start with a new Express project and I already hit a snag. I used the generator to start my app (`express --view=handlebars sms_alarm_nodejs`) and I got this error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\views"
application.js:630
    at Function.render (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:971:7)
    at c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\app.js:43:7
    at Layer.handle_error (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (c:\Users\joe_t\workspace\sms_alarm_nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
```

Am I missing a view reference in app.js? I assumed the app generator would handle this for me to start. And can I use handlebars? The sample I saw used pug.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I had to use `--view=hbs` as the generator parameter.